# The Hebrew Language are not Supported in Chrome

Tags: php, flash, codeigniter

How to enable Hebrew Language in codeigniter controller file?

Some of the Hebrew Context are not Supported in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You have option in codeignter to support multi language .

In application folder you have language folder

**Define your language keys**

$lang['language_key'] = "The actual message to be shown";

**Load your language**

$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');

**Get your key word**

$msg = $this->lang->line('language_key');

for flash massage also we can define

**ex:**

$this->session->set_flashdata("msg",$msg);

Refer this

[tutroial](http://sumonbd.wordpress.com/2009/09/16/develop-multilingual-site-using-codeigniter-i18n-library/)